# Cannot completely disable DPI scaling

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, dpi, scaling, high-dpi

I have an old (1995 old) image program that needs to display high-resolution images.

I tried different settings, but I always get one of the following effects:

**Display at 200% scale, run program normally:** the program completely displays at 200% and I actually see less image detail than my old PC. I didn't buy a high-res screen to see less-res.

**Display at 200% scale, run program with "Disable display scaling on high DPI setting":** Image in the application displays 1:1 which is what I want, but the interface is completely screwed up. Three quarters of the GUI elements display at 200% and often their contents only occupy the upper-left quarter.

**Display at 100% scale, program run normally:** the program completely displays at 100% (what I want!) but all other windows programs too, and I can't read **** anymore.

Why does the "Disable display scaling on high DPI setting" in the shortcut properties not work as advertised?? I read multiple pages and fora on this subject and in the end they all simply recommend enabling this option, and everyone seems happy, so why isn't it working here?

Comment: Have you considered setting the DPI to 100% and set the font size to everything to a higher size? It will not scale everything, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Tried that in the past on windows 7 and it screws up more than it does good (something like the inverse of case #2 in my question). I tried it now and same result. I changed all 6 types of font to double their size, but dialog and menu bar text size is not changed. http://i.imgur.com/KP5dX7a.png

Comment: Hmm yeah, that doesn't work. It was worth a try though.